# unity camera not showing the scene objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, game-development

Why isn't my camera showing anything even though I have objects and camera is in perfect spot?

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/k68vb.jpg)]

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tExZ.jpg)]

I tried aligning it to my position and everything but nothing worked and I am using unity urp engine.

Comment: well you can see in the scene edit window your camera isnt pointing at the things you think it is. or the settings on it prevent them from showing..